# Deserialize a JSON to Class

Tags: c#, deserialization

I am trying to desrialize this string:

```
storage = "{\"1\":{\"1\":\"aaa\"},\"2\":{\"1\":\"bbb\"}}";
```

it works:

```
var LocalStorageOBJ1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<DataModels.StoragePrimaryKeys,
                                                    Dictionary<DataModels.StorageSecondaryKeys, string>>>(storage);
```

But I want to do it with a class, something like:

```
var LocalStorageOBJ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(storage);
```

`MyClass` is:

```
public class DataModels
{
    public enum StoragePrimaryKeys
    {
        Login = 1,
        Account = 2
    };

    public enum StorageSecondaryKeys
    {
        JobTitle = 1,
        JobId = 2,
        JobLocation = 3,
        RenewDate = 4,
        ExpirationDate = 5
    };
}


public class MyClass
{
    public Dictionary<DataModels.StoragePrimaryKeys, ForiegnData> PrimaryDictionary { get; set; }
}
public class ForiegnData
{
    public Dictionary<DataModels.StorageSecondaryKeys, string> ForeignDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, I got null when I deserialized it.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyClass is not

```
Dictionary<DataModels.StoragePrimaryKeys, Dictionary<DataModels.StorageSecondaryKeys, string>>
```

MyClass HAS

```
Dictionary<DataModels.StoragePrimaryKeys, Dictionary<DataModels.StorageSecondaryKeys, string>>
```

So you should encapsulate the JSON string properly:

```
{\"PrimaryDictionary\" : {\"1\":{\"1\":\"aaa\"},\"2\":{\"1\":\"bbb\"}}}
```

Comment: Thank you but ut doesn't work.. I have got null in PrimaryDictionary variable of MyClass..

Comment: MyClass is not Dictionary<DataModels.StoragePrimaryKeys,                                                   Dictionary<DataModels.StorageSecondaryKeys, string>>. MyClass HAS Dictionary<DataModels.StoragePrimaryKeys,                                                   Dictionary<DataModels.StorageSecondaryKeys, string>>. So maybe you have to add another encapsulation ({ } to the beginning and to the end)

Comment: Can you explain it please?

{ } to the beginning and to the end

Comment: @AlonShmiel Your json represents a dictionary. Your code represents a class which contains a dictionary.

Comment: I understood it, so I changed storage variable to:
"{{\"1\":{\"1\":\"aaa\"},\"2\":{\"1\":\"bbb\"}}}"
And it doesn't work.. Does it what Cem means?

Comment: Can you please try {"PrimaryDictionary" : {\"1\":{\"1\":\"aaa\"},\"2\":{\"1\":\"bbb\"}}}